# datetime variable with extra hour and custom format as datetime not string

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetime-format

This is so simple but i am not able to figure out how to do it, please excuse my ignorance.

I would like a datetime variable to be current datetime + 1 hour in the format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"

I have tried this so far (dotnetfiddle.net) and when i assign it to the datetime variable the date is changed to slashes instead of hypen.

```
Imports System

    Public Module Module1
        Public Sub Main()
            Dim tet As String = Datetime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd hh:mm:ss")
            Dim expiryTime As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            Console.WriteLine(convert.todatetime(tet))
            Console.WriteLine(tet)
            Console.WriteLine(Datetime.Now.AddHours(1))
        End Sub
    End Module
```

As per one of the comments I have used parseExact and i still see the date with slashes instead of hypen

[image: screenshot]

Comment: *I would like a datetime ... in the format "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"* And what prevents you from doing it?

Comment: The format you see in the IDE has nothing to do with what will come out of your program.

Comment: @AndrewMorton really sorry i didnt know that. I am posting this expiry time to an API which requires the value to be datetime and in the above format but after the post expiry time is never set

Answer (score 1):

When you convert `tet` back to a `DateTime` it will display as the default pattern. Keep it as a string for display. The convert it back with `ParseExact` when you need to use it as `DateTime` again.

```
Dim dNow As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)
Dim strNow As String = dNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
Console.WriteLine(strNow)
```

Comment: Don't convert it back. In your example, `dtNow` is that `DateTime` value so use it if/when you need that `DateTime` value. Use `strNow` for display or serialisation but there's no point to converting back to a value you already had in the first place.